# How to Disable Windows Authentication in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2014, security, authentication, azure, windows-server

I would like to say that as per my Organization requirement they want to Disable Windows Authentication in SQL Server.

```
My Environment is as follows:-

1) Microsoft Azure 
2) Windows Server 2016
3) Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Standard
4) AD is in office 365 and also synchronize with Exchange Server
```

As I have gone through some SQL Server blog like [How to Disable Windows Authentication in SQL Server](https://www.top-password.com/blog/how-to-disable-windows-authentication-in-sql-server/) but might be I have miss somewhere to disable windows authentication in SQL Server.

Any suggestion or help will be appreciated.

Comment: I think you can't. But you can try to deny access to all windows (groups/users) accounts.

Comment: Just pointing out that of the two choices that is the worst security option, see [this under appreciated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46452638/2112418)

Comment: I would be questioning who created that rule because Microsoft Security recommends use of Windows Auth over SQL Logins. As well, SQL Server itself utilizes Windows Authentication so you won't be able to abide by the letter of that rule/law.

Answer (score 4):

To stop Windows users from logging in, don't create logins for them in SQL Server.

By default, just because someone has a Windows login doesn't mean they have permissions in SQL Server. You have to use the [CREATE LOGIN command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-login-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to map Windows users to SQL Server permissions.

If you don't do that, they can't log in.

Your organization may also be asking for a list of people and groups who already have logins, and who need to be removed. In SQL Server Management Studio, go into Security, Logins as described in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/create-a-login?view=sql-server-2017), and you can review the list of logins from there, and disable (or drop) logins who shouldn't have access.

Comment: Thanks for response. I would like to say that , this is the new setup in Microsoft azure. Till now no one "Windows users login has created in SQL Server". Even i wouldn't install the MS SQL server in Azure through "Domain login Administrator". I have install MS SQL Server through "Local O.S administrator" i,e, Built-In login administrator.

Answer (score 1):

Its not possible to disable Windows Authentication mode in SQL Server. You can only disable SQL Server authentication by selecting ' Windows Authentication mode' in Sever Properties>Security or have a mixed mode.
What your article is referring to , is how to disable particular windows logins which already exist on the SQL server.

HTH.